# ASP.NET Core 5 JwtBearer dynamic secret based on User

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to create simple API with JWT authentication, where **each user** has **different secret** key, instead of one global secret. Which sounds like simple problem, but the tricky question is **how to correctly get UserManager in StartUp** for validation.

First and obvious approach would be via Dependency Injection, looking like that:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
public UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager { get; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
{
        Configuration = configuration;
        UserManager = userManager;
}
```

But that will immediately crash with error: "*System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1*"

So second attempt was with BuildServiceProvider:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
       ...
       UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
       ...
}
```

That actually works, but with that ugly warning: "*ASP0000: Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependecy injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'.*"

After some time i came up with third final solution:

```
private IApplicationBuilder _app;

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
       ...
       _app = app;
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
       ...
       services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(options => {
           options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
           {
               ValidateIssuer = true,
               ValidateAudience = true,
               ValidateLifetime = true,
               ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
               ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
               IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, kid, validationParameters) =>
               {
                   List<SecurityKey> keys = new List<SecurityKey>();

                   JwtSecurityToken jwtToken = (JwtSecurityToken)securityToken;
                   Claim claimName = jwtToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
                   if (claimName != null)
                   {
                       string name = claimName.Value;
                       using IServiceScope serviceScope = _app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
                       UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
                       IdentityUser user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(name).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                       if (user != null) keys.Add(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user.JwtSecret)));
                   }

                   return keys;
               },
               //IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Secret"])),
               ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
           };
       });
}
```

That one solution works, no warnings or bugs so far, but is it clean?
Can i improve it or should i take different approach i didnt think of?
Do not be so harsh on me - i am pretty much newbie with ASP ;)

If You have made it so far and/or will give me any tips i will be more than appreciated. Thanks.